# java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'admin'

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

Disclaimer: I have never used SQL server before.

I am trying to connect to SQL server Express using java code.

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/POC;instance=MOHITCH-LAPTOP/SQLEXPRESS";
        String user = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement ();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from POC.dbo.poc_table");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
            }
        }
    }
```

**And I am getting the exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'admin'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:603)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:352)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:185)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at my.java.Test1.main(Test1.java:16)
```

I also tried logging in using MS SQL server Management Studio 2014. And I **successfully** did it.

[image]

Here is my database structure: 
[image]

Any help is highly appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: Is the credential for user `admin` correct?

Comment: Not sure about SQL Server, but in Oracle there is a permission `CREATE SESSION` which is required if you want to login.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I am able to login using MS SQL server Management Studio. Only problem is with the java code and when I tried this java code on a different machine it worked, which means my installation might have some issue but I am not able to figure that out. I am using windows 7 64 bit machine, with 64 bit java and 64 bit SQL server 2008 Express.

Comment: @EMM, What is the solution for this ? did any answers here help?

Comment: @rinilnath it was a long time back and the provided answers didn't help at that time so I didn't accept any. I think it had something to do with my machine config.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to modify some configuration in your server.

Please follow the below step and hope this will help you.

```
1. Open your SQL Server Management Studio.

2. Database server right click and go to properties.

3. Choose Security option and check SQL Server and Windows authentication mode.

4. Enable TCP/IP connection in SQL Configuration Manager.

5. Restart your SQL server service.
```

Comment: Hero of the day! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all ensure that SQL Browser Service is running - in windows control panel services. 
If you can don't use JTDS driver there is Microsoft's official driver - according to different benchmarks it is slightly slower but it is the most comprehensive implementation - you will find a lot of problems with JTDS (something is not supported or simply not working and no one bothers to fix it, version 1.3 is not working in JDK6).

Connection string, that is enough (instance not needed for express version):

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/MyDatabase
```

If you used MS driver connection string would be:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase
```